# I get error saying my stored procedure returns more that one value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-migration

Code works perfectly on Oracle development when I copy it over to SQL Server Management Studio, it now complains that the subquery returns more than one value.

Change the syntax from Oracle to SQL Server.

It's supposed to pull all vacant posts for HR, but it throws the error below. In Oracle, it works fine.

```
SELECT
    CASE
       WHEN A.POST_TYPE IN ('1PFT', '1PPT', '2PFT', '2PPT', '2RFT', '2RPT', '3PFT', '3PPT', '3RFT', '3RPT', '1LTC', '2LTC')
          THEN 'EQUITY PERM TARGET'
       WHEN A.POST_TYPE IN ('1PFO', '2PFO', '3PFO', '1LTO', '2LTO')
          THEN 'EQUITY EXTERNAL TARGET'
       WHEN A.POST_TYPE IN ('1LAF','1LAP','2LAF','2LAP','3LAF','3LAP')
          THEN 'LRAA POST'
       ELSE 'EQUITY OTHER'
    END AS POST_TYPE_DESCRIPTION,
    CASE 
       WHEN A.CAMPUS = '1' THEN 'SUMMERSTRAND CAMPUS SOUTH'
       WHEN A.CAMPUS = '2' THEN 'SUMMERSTRAND CAMPUS NORTH'
       WHEN A.CAMPUS = '3' THEN 'GEORGE CAMPUS'
       WHEN A.CAMPUS = '4' THEN 'SECOND AVENUE CAMPUS'
       WHEN A.CAMPUS = '5' THEN 'MISSIONVALE'
       WHEN A.CAMPUS = '7' THEN 'BIRD STREET CAMPUS'
       WHEN A.CAMPUS = '11' THEN 'OCEAN SCIENCES CAMPUS'
       WHEN A.CAMPUS = '92' THEN 'EAST LONDON'
       WHEN A.CAMPUS = '98' THEN 'OFF CAMPUS'
       WHEN A.CAMPUS = '99' THEN 'NO CAMPUS'
    END AS CAMPUS_NAME,
    (SELECT DISTINCT NSACAD.FACULTY_CODE
     FROM NMMU_HOD_VIEW NSACAD
     WHERE NSACAD.DEPARTMENT_CODE = A.POST_DEPARTMENT) AS POST_FACULTY_CODE,
    (SELECT DISTINCT NSACAD.FACULTY_NAME
     FROM NMMU_HOD_VIEW NSACAD
     WHERE NSACAD.DEPARTMENT_CODE = A.POST_DEPARTMENT) AS POST_FACULTY_DIRECTORATE_NAME,
    A.*,
    (SELECT --ISNULL((MAX(Y.EXPIRE_DATE)), 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'POST_NEVER_EVER_FILLED' )
         ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(Date, Y.EXPIRE_DATE, 111)), 'POST_NEVER_EVER_FILLED')
     FROM  
         M42V_PERSONNEL_SERVICE_RECORDS Y
     WHERE 
         (Y.POST_CODE = POST_CODE)
         AND (Y.EQUITY_STATUS = 'P')) AS DATE_LAST_PERM_PERSON_LEFT
FROM 
    NMMUPOSTSTRUCTURE A
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT *
     FROM M42V_PERSONNEL_SERVICE_RECORDS X
     WHERE X.EQUITY_STATUS IN ('P', 'T', 'O')
       AND (X.START_DATE < CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), EOMONTH(GETDATE(), 105)))
       AND (X.EXPIRE_DATE IS NULL OR X.EXPIRE_DATE > GETDATE())) B ON A.POST_CODE = B.POST_CODE
WHERE 
    (B.PERSONNEL_NUMBER IS NULL OR B.EQUITY_STATUS <> 'P')
    AND (A.POST_TYPE NOT IN ('F15'))
    AND (A.POST_TYPE IN ('1PFT', '2PFT', '2PPT', '3PFT', '3PPT', '1PPT', '2RFT', '2RPT', '3RFT', '3RPT', '1LAF', '2LAF', '2PFO', '2PPO', '3PFO','1LTC','2LTC','1LTO','2LTO'))
    AND (A.POST_STATUS IN ('A'))

    --AND ( (SELECT DISTINCT NSACAD.FACULTY_CODE
    --       FROM LOCAL.NMMU_HOD_VIEW NSACAD
    --      WHERE NSACAD.DEPARTMENT_CODE = A.POST_DEPARTMENT) IN (:FacultyDirectorateCodes) )
    --AND (A.POST_DEPARTMENT                              IN (:DepartmentCodes))
ORDER BY 
    A.POST_DEPARTMENT_DESC, A.POST_CODE ASC, B.START_DATE DESC
```

Comment: Post your script.

Comment: you have to at least show us your query for us to help you

Comment: The error seems to be telling you the problem here. This is one of the more descriptive errors messages in SQL Server; what about the error don't you understand and we can try to elaborate more for you, so you understand what the error means.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't expect SQL written for Oracle to simply work in SQL Server. Every RDBMS uses a different dialect of SQL; here we have PL\SQL and T-SQL respectively. Every dialect has different syntax (although similar), different functions, behaviour, and none of them support all (or the same) ISO rules. You almost always have to change your SQL whenever you migrate, apart from with the very simplest of statements.

Comment: where is query?

Comment: Okay, let me try to post the code for you to have an idea of what could perhaps cause the error. I'm sorry, I'm new here. Thought the would be a step im asked to put in my code. I probably missed the step.

Comment: I recommend taking the [tour] and reading [ask], it'll help give you an idea of how to ask questions in a way that's most likely to get good answers :-)

Comment: You should always read your question back after you post it, so you can see what we see. Most questions on SO really need a problem statement, sufficient code that we can reproduce any errors you're getting and a statement of what you want to actually have happen so we know what answer to give

Comment: You say _Code works perfectly on Oracle_. I say it just looks like that because your Oracle table has other data than the SQL Server table.

Comment: Posted my query as instructed please have a look and tell where I'm getting my script  wrong

Comment: Your select for `DATE_LAST_PERM_PERSON_LEFT` is almost certainly returning multiple rows. It doesn't seem to be checking `PERSONNEL_NUMBER` in its where clause. Try commenting that out to see if the error goes away.

Comment: Okay, let me try that. I had a major problem with that last time I run the query. I had to change the convert Function, if you can see there i commented it out and tried something else. Yes i saw it, the problem  it is there. after I commented DATE_LAST_PERM_PERSON_LEFT out the error was not there. It pulled perfectly. I'll try making adjustments on that section. Thank you a lot :)

Comment: Execute your sub queries (2 or 3) separately for a specific A.POST_DEPARTMENT and check how many rows are returned from each Sub Query. The rules is, no sub query can return more than 1 row. And the error indication one of your sub query returning more than one rows!!

Answer (score 1):

In and of itself this error is similar on both SQL Server and Oracle:

- In Oracle: "ORA-01427: Subquery returns more than one row"
- In SQL Server: "Subquery returned more than 1 value."

It happens when you've written a query where you try to compare a single value with the output of a query that returns multiple values. This isn't allowed. You can't have X on the left equal to Y and Z on the right

These queries cause the error:

```
-- Oracle
select 1 from dual where 1 = (select 1 from dual union all select 2 from dual)

-- SQL Server
select 1 where 1 = (select 1 union all select 2)
```

For both SQL Server and Oracle, the query in brackets returns two rows. You cannot compare a single value on the left with 2 values on the right, for operators like =, >, < etc

These queries are fine:

```
-- Oracle
select 1 from dual where 1 = (select 1 from dual)

-- SQL Server
select 1 where 1 = (select 1)
```

If the query in brackets returns only one value then the SQL will run in both Oracle and SQL Server. The reason your query works in Oracle but not SQL Server is not because of a difference in the implementation of the database product itself, it's *the data in the database*; your Oracle database *data* is such that the subquery is only returning one value because there is only one value to return from the data. As soon as someone adds another value *to the data* that causes the subquery to return two rows, the query will start to fail in oracle too

You must either modify your subquery to return one value (use an aggregator function like MAX, MIN etc) or you must modify your query to use IN, ANY, ALL or some other operator that accepts a set on the right hand side:

```
-- Oracle

-- a MAX function without a group by is guaranteed to return a single value (one row, one column)
select 1 from dual where 1 = (select max (x) from (select 1 as x from dual union all select 2 from dual) y)

-- the IN operator accepts a set on the right
select 1 from dual where 1 IN (select 1 as x from dual union all select 2 from dual)

-- modifying = with ANY or ALL accepts a set on the right
select 1 from dual where 1 = ANY (select 1 as x from dual union all select 2 from dual)

-- SQL Server
select 1 where 1 = (select max (x) from (select 1 as x union all select 2) y)
select 1 where 1 IN (select 1 union all select 2)
select 1 where 1 > ALL (select 1 union all select 2) --note: this WHERE is false, no rows result
```

Or you must modify the way you wrote your query to use a JOIN/EXISTS operator (I won't add an example because it starts to detract from the specific question being answered

Comment: Thank you very for  your assistance. Ima try making adjustments on the code and see if your info help. Thanks again Caius Jard